# Why is my Service stopping?

Tags: android, service, android-context

I wonder what conditions must be met so Android stops a `Service`, besides the obvious, running low on memory.

See, I run a bootstrapping `Service`, holding a local `BroadcastReceiver`. The service itself contains a state machine and so I transition from one bootstrapping state to another. Each states transition function starts either an `AsyncTask` or an `IntentService` and once it's done, it dispatches an `Intent` back to *Service* to let it know that the task was executed successfully. However, during that, the service just stops, and thus the intent is being dispatched into nothing, which is frustrating.

I don't want to use a Foreground Service and I don't want to trick around just to keep my service alive. I also don't want to rely on `onHandleIntent()` of an `IntentService`, since the `IntentService` looses all its states, meaning all members get nulled once ran through, so when stateA is finished and stateB should be kicked off, the whole statemachine is null, all previous states are gone, etc....

I commit the `Services` context to each `IntentService`/`AsnycTask` and I thought, as long as they hold a reference of the service context, the `Service` wont stop. Sadly, this is not the case...

Do I have to invoke a method on the context while `doInBackground()` an `AsyncTask`, just to keep the `Service` alive or something?

Answer (score 0):

Beside system running out of memory, you can get your process killed if you exceed certain amount of memory with your service([check limitations](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#MultipleProcesses)).

Like with service processes, foreground processes can extend your service's lifespan, but you have no guarantees either.

I think your best shot is making a logic that will go with services in START_STICKY mode([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)).

Comment: Debugging on a 2gb ram Nexus 5 here, this is not a resource issue.

Comment: Though I know that each process has a limited amount of resource, yes... Still, there is nothing particularly heavy going on. Making small json requests, retrieving small json results. Sending data sms, receiving gcm notifications, that kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder what conditions must be met so Android stops a Service, besides the obvious, running low on memory.

A service can be stopped by the user at any time for any reason, either by directly stopping the individual service, or (more likely) by terminating the whole process.

Android will stop a service individually if it crashes. More commonly, it terminates the entire process to reclaim that process' memory for other uses.

> I run a bootstrapping Service, holding a local BroadcastReceiver

I doubt anyone but you knows what "bootstrapping" means in this context.

> Each states transition function starts either an AsyncTask or an IntentService and once it's done, it dispatches an Intent back to Service to let it know that the task was executed successfully.

Using an `AsyncTask` from a `Service` is frequently pointless. You do not want to do stuff on the main application thread in a `Service`, and the point behind an `AsyncTask` is to do some work on the main application thread (e.g., `onPostExecute()`). Use a `Thread`.

Using an `IntentService` from a `Service` is pointless and wasteful. You already have a `Service` -- it's doing the "bootstrapping". You do not need *another* `Service`. Use a `Thread`.

> However, during that, the service just stops, and thus the intent is being dispatched into nothing, which is frustrating.

More likely, the whole process is gone.

> I commit the Services context to each IntentService/AsnycTask

I am not completely clear what "commit" means here, but if you are passing a `Context` (`Service`) to another `Context` (`IntentService`), that is a serious code smell.

> as long as they hold a reference of the service context, the service wont stop

No. Moreover, none of that stops Android from terminating your process.

> Do I have to invoke a method on the context while doInBackground() an AsyncTask, just to keep the Service alive or something?

No, you need to keep your state machine persistent (a.k.a., a file), so that if your process terminates for whatever reason, when you next run again, you can pick up from where you left off.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input, I assume I do not aggree with your comments at all is because I have given too little info about what I do, though the text is already pretty long. 1.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping 2.) https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java - as far as I can see it, AsyncTask is just a Wrapper for ExecutorService. Please elaborate why it is pointless to use this wrapper 3.) The whole process is not gone, the service does not run in its own process,...

Comment: ... the main activity is still running after Service.onDestroy() is being invoked automagically... 4.) Committing is the correct term, thanks. My explaination was misleading, I use a Manager-Class, passing the context along. I need that context for different things. The manager invokes an execute Method which then runs the AsyncTask. onPostExecute() calls an OnSuccess/Fail method, which then dispatches the appropriate intent.

Comment: 5.) I do not need to keep the whole state machine persistent. I only have to keep the current state persistent. But, a statemachine is pointless when I have to reinit it every time onHandleIntent() is being invoked. I could pull it out directly and simply react to the received intent extra...

Comment: @JohnSmith: "Please elaborate why it is pointless to use this wrapper" -- if you want an `ExecutorService`, use `ExecutorService`. In fact, you are specifically misusing `AsyncTask`, having it do work on the main application thread (`onPostExecute()`) in your service, which is unnecessary and a code smell. "the main activity is still running after Service.onDestroy() is being invoked automagically" -- then either you are calling `stopService()`, you are calling `stopSelf()`, the user is stopping the service, your service has an unhandled exception, or you are misinterpreting your debug output.

Comment: Sorry, but I have the feeling you are misunderstanding on purpose. I run my background stuff in background, once it is finished, I eval the returned result, a boolean. If it is true, I dispatch an success Intent, false fail Intent. There is nothing wrong with sending Intents from the main thread. You are right though, using the AsyncTask is not necessary, I could use a thread instead, or a newSingleThreadExecutor(), yes. This is not the point. But for the sake of argument, I will replace AsyncTasks with Threads and see that nothing changes with regards to my problem.

Comment: @JohnSmith: "There is nothing wrong with sending Intents from the main thread" -- yes, there is, when it is not necessary to do so. First, there is only one main application thread, and when your code is tying it up, it cannot do anything else, such as process UI events. Second, doing work on the main application thread from your service temporarily puts the process in the foreground group, giving it access to more CPU cycles, to the detriment of whatever is really running in the foreground.

Comment: @JohnSmith: "and see that nothing changes with regards to my problem" -- I never claimed that it would. However, it is an issue with your approach, which is why I mentioned it. Again, if you are absolutely sure that the process itself is not being terminated, then then either you are calling `stopService()`, you are calling `stopSelf()`, the user is stopping the service, your service has an unhandled exception, or you are misinterpreting your debug output. Android does not stop services due to low memory conditions -- it terminates entire processes.

Comment: I dont know what causes my issue. I will add some code now, since I am still pretty interested in the reason, though I have said good bye to my previous approach, got rid of the SM and use a different approach, which saves me a bunch of codelines anyway. I just want to stress, strict mode is enabled, there is nothing blocking the main-thread.